# UITableView jumping down Navigation toolbar when trying to go to another page

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

[image: Glitch]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8e55.gif

I make a tableview and when I touched on a cell it will go to another page. I implement a Navigation toolbar, and a searchbar on the top navigation bar (With large title).

Everything looks good but when I touch the very bottom cell, the original tableview will suddenly jumped down to the toolbar, which looks annoying.

In didSelectRow method I only implement this code to deselect the cell, while I get rid of this code the problem still exists.

```
// CANCEL THE HIGHLIGHT AFTER TOUCHING
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView .deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

I tried using `tableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never` and implement self-defined `tableView.contentInset`, the large-title style top bar makes it a little messy to adjust the `contentInset`.

This is my storyboard:

[image: Storyboard]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/5vsdu.jpg

I wonder if there's any simple solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Make sure in didSelectRow Method no need to reload the tableview.

2) And I think navigation bar should be same size for every viewcontroller.

Comment: well it seems in didselectrow method, I only apply a tableView .deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true) methods and it seems to be nothing to do with this problem, and my navigation bar already been set as the same. I think it's maybe in something related to content insect, and it might could be solved by simply setting up some storyboard attributions.... But I don't know whether to solve it...